# Custom event notification that trigger Lamda functions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In AWS, we can create a event notification from S3 bucket that trigger a lambda function. Is it possible for me the create such a custom event to lambda functions. More specifically, I have a lambda function A that creates 5 files when it is trigger, however, sometimes, the error might happen and it only creates 3 or 4 files. I want to set a restriction time 5 minutes for this lambda function A to run. If 5 minutes is over, it will send a event notification that contains the information of how many files were created by A to another lambda function B. Is it possible to create such a event notification from lambda function A that contains the number of files created by A to lambda function B and trigger B  ?

**Note** : This lambda function B should be trigger only once and it receives all information of how many files that were created.

**What I've tried so far:** When lambda function A creates output files, I save these files in a S3 bucket and and set the lambda function B triggered by this S3 bucket. By doing that, I can receive the information of the created files. But this will trigger lambda function B many times (it is triggered when any new file is created) and separately. That is not what I want to do. I want the lambda function B be triggered only once and receive the information of files at once when lambda function A finishes. So this approach is not working.

**Edit**: Thanks Marcin for providing me a solution in case only one lambda function A creates 5 files. I would like to ask what if the these 5 files are created by 5 different lambda functions ? Is is possible to do that ?

Comment: Ok, but what is your specific problem?

Comment: @Marcin The problem is to create a event notification from lambda function A that contains the number of files created by A to lambda function B and trigger B ? Is it possible to create such a custom event notification ?

Comment: I see. You have to describe what exactly you have tried so far, and why it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> set the lambda function B triggered by this S3 bucket.

It would be better if instead of doing this, you would setup **SQS queue**. So lambda A would publish a message to the SQS queue once it finishes with the file. The new lambda B would be then triggered by a new message in the SQS:

```
Lambda A ---> SQS ---> Lambda B
```

Comment: What if 5 files are created by 5 different lambda functions. Will your solution work ?